# Error Java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: windows, filenotfoundexception

In my project i read excel file. this functionality working on local host but i upload this project on server that time i get error like below

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:/Java_Question.xls (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
```

Controller.AdminExelSheetController.read(AdminExelSheetController.jav                                                                                        a:190)
Why this error on server?

Read excel file code: Here where changes required ?

```
FileInputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream("D:/" + fileName);
POIFSFileSystem systemFile = new POIFSFileSystem(inputFile);
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(systemFile);
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
if (!"".equals(rows.toString())) {
while (rows.hasNext()) {
HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
Vector cellStore = new Vector();
while (cells.hasNext()) {
HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
cellStore.addElement(cell);
}rowStore.addElement(cellStore);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your project has a different path on the server. 
You should get your file path like this...

```
String path = ServletContext.getRealPath("/FolderInYourProjectWhereExcelIsLocated");
```

Comment: @leskover .. Where i add this path

Comment: @leskover I add my read excel file code above please check it and tell me where i add String path ?

Comment: I want solution how i implement code for read excel file from server

Comment: String path = ServletContext.getRealPath("/FolderInYourProjectWhereExcelIsLocated");Where i implement above code